# Renaming .jpg files in the sub-folders

Tags: bash, file-rename, gnu-parallel

I have a large number of files in sub-folders that I need to rename. For example, I have:

```
ParentFolder/sub-Folders/*.jpg
```

How can I copy the files with a new naming convention as follows?

```
ParentFolder1.jpg
ParentFolder2.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rename over the full path using file globbing :

```
*/*
```

If you don't understand, you can test it with :

```
echo */*
```

First * is your directory, second * is your file name. Catch them in a regular expression :

```
(.*)/(.*)
```

Now $1 is your parent folder name and $2 is your file name. You can easily build your solution like this :

```
rename -n "s/(.*)\/(.*)/\$1\/\$1\$2/" */*
```

It keeps directory structure and adds directory name as a prefix to each of its files. You could move your files up by simply changing `\$1\/\$1\$2` to `\$1\$2`. You then just have to delete empty directories using rmdir.

I voluntarily added the option -n so you don't do a mess if you copy-paste. Simply remove the option when you think it's good.

```
    adrien@adrienLT:~/Documents/PEV$ cp -r Holiday/ Holiday_copy/
adrien@adrienLT:~/Documents/PEV$ tree Holiday*
Holiday
├── France
│   ├── 1.jpg
│   ├── 2.jpg
│   └── 3.jpg
├── Italy1
│   ├── 1.jpg
│   ├── 2.jpg
│   └── 3.jpg
└── Italy2
    ├── 1.jpg
    ├── 2.jpg
    └── 3.jpg
Holiday_copy
├── France
│   ├── 1.jpg
│   ├── 2.jpg
│   └── 3.jpg
├── Italy1
│   ├── 1.jpg
│   ├── 2.jpg
│   └── 3.jpg
└── Italy2
    ├── 1.jpg
    ├── 2.jpg
    └── 3.jpg

6 directories, 18 files
adrien@adrienLT:~/Documents/PEV$ cd Holiday_copy/
adrien@adrienLT:~/Documents/PEV/Holiday_copy$ rename "s/(.*)\/(.*)/\$1\/\$1\$2/" */*
adrien@adrienLT:~/Documents/PEV/Holiday_copy$ tree .
.
├── France
│   ├── France1.jpg
│   ├── France2.jpg
│   └── France3.jpg
├── Italy1
│   ├── Italy11.jpg
│   ├── Italy12.jpg
│   └── Italy13.jpg
└── Italy2
    ├── Italy21.jpg
    ├── Italy22.jpg
    └── Italy23.jpg

3 directories, 9 files
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is via [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). Tutorial [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html):

```
find ./ParentFolder -name "*.jpg" | parallel "mv {} DESTINATION/ParentFolder{#}.jpg"
```

To view the commands to be run before executing them, try:

```
find ./ParentFolder -name "*.jpg" | parallel --dryrun "mv {} DESTINATION/ParentFolder{#}.jpg"
```

Comment: ah, `--dryrun`, even better! Good luck to all.